# Determining the area between two polar curves using a double integral

Tags: calculus

Use a double integral in polar coordinates to ﬁnd the area of the region inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ but outside the circle $(x − 1)^2 + y^2 = 1.$

Attempt:

**Area 1**

$$x^2+y^2=4$$

$$r=2$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 r \,dr\,d\theta$$

**Area 2**

$$(x-1)^2+y^2= 1$$

$$r=2\cosθ$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\cosθ} r \,dr\,d\theta$$

$$\text{Area} = \text{Area} 1 - \text{Area} 2 $$

Is the set up ok? Im not sure if the region of integration is correct.

Comment: Where you wrote things like $x^2$+$y^2$=1, I changed it to $x^2+y^2=1$. That is proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the first area this is correct.
- For the second one you obtain:
  $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \cos(\theta)} r \,dr \,d\theta=\int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \cos^2(\theta) \,d \theta=2 \pi$$
  but the correct result is $\pi$ as it is a circle of radius $1$.

The problem is that by taking $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ you go through the circle two times.

In my opinion the best way to avoid the problem is to write:
$$\text{Area}_2 =\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \chi_{0 \leq r \leq 2 \cos(\theta)} r \,dr \,d\theta$$
so you obtain:
$$\text{Area}_2 =\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\cos(2 \theta} 1 r \,dr \,d\theta$$
which give $\pi$ as expected.